# How to Fix "UnityPlayer.dll failed with output: Copying the file failed: Data error (cyclic redundancy check)" error when building a unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to make a rythm game using Unity, Mirror, and Fizzysteamworks, and whenever I try to build the program (for windows, intel 64 bit), I keep getting this error `Building Builds\Build1\UnityPlayer.dll failed with output: Copying the file failed: Data error (cyclic redundancy check).` 
I dont get this error however, when I build it in developer mode

I tried making an empty game except for a Main Camera and a Directional Light and I made sure that the project name and all the game objects had no spaces in their names (I renamed Main Camera to MainCamera and Directional Light to DirectionalLight), and I still got this error when trying to build. I want my Mirror Fizzysteamworks game to be able to build so I can test it in steam the steam lobbys, and joining players. If anybody else had this problem, how did you fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately your question doesn't really meet the standards that the community expects here so I don't think you're likely to get many decent responses. Consider checking [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updating your question if you can. Good luck!